# Eel and python - how can hide cmd window when the app is running

Tags: python-3.x, eel

I have created a simple html page and used it in a python app with the help of [Eel](https://github.com/ChrisKnott/Eel)
Everything works fine but I want to hide the cmd window that opens up when the python app is running and just show the html page that eel is opening. how can I achieve this? is this an eel specific matter or its a python issue?
thanks.
I have tried to do it with `.pyw` extension but in that case the html will not open up either.

Comment: If you are using Pyinstaller you can pass --windowed option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is normal, because for each program the python console will appear, because you are running it from the python launcher or cmd

If you want to hide it, you have to compile it and select to hide the console in the setup to do that you can use the module [auto-py-to-exe](https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/) (which, btw. is made with [eel](https://github.com/samuelhwilliams/Eel)). It uses [pyinstaler](https://pypi.org/project/PyInstaller/). You can also use pyinstaller directly.